# Why does Tkinter lag only the first time a listbox is populated with a large number of lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

My application, written for Python 3.12.0, loads a large number (around 6,000+ lines) of text lines into a Tkinter Listbox like this:

```
   self.listbox.delete(0,tk.END)

   self.listbox.insert(tk.END,*filtered_files)
```

Where `filtered_files` is a List of textual file names. I heard this was more performant than to insert the filenames one by one, so I just feed a big  list into the method.

However, when this operation is run (I confirmed via profiling that this is indeed the operation), the first time, it takes 1-2 seconds and blocks the UI. However, subsequent times this and other similar operations are run by the program, they appear to occur instantaneously in the UI, even when the list data is entirely different. Why is this?

Comment: Sorry I cannot replicate this (I created simple app with Listbox with 6000 lines) and it loads them instantly. How do you populate the `filtered_files`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely `filtered_files = [filepath for filepath in self.loaded_filepaths if "term" in filepath]` but note that this should not matter because I profiled this and it only takes 4-5ms to execute with the provided data. The lag i am perceiving is much longer than that.

Comment: @AndrejKesely so weird, I can continually reproduce this issue every time, even as I add more functionality to the app. It's one of those tough to debug issues. Whichever button I click first to do a filter operation always ends up in the lag, I assume the lag is internal to Tk. There's probably a way for me to somehow profile the library and figure it out.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Ok, I think I figured out what is going on... So, first, I grossly understated how many items are in this listbox... There are 71,000+ items in it upon initialization/app start. So, what's happening doesn't so much involve the loading of the 1,000-6,000 items that get populated when the buttons are clicked, as it does that Tk is having to clear 71,000 items OUT of the listbox, hence the lag only occurs once, because it's occurring due to the removal of the items rather than the insertion of the new ones. I need to think about if I can maybe incrementally update the listbox.

Comment: Just wanted to also state that I realize I didn't put the full program context here, but as these items are loaded out of a data file, it wouldn't have helped to understand this problem anyway.